# install4j IDE won't recognize my custom screen

Tags: java, eclipse, screen, install4j

We are porting all of our custom code from Installshield (very old version) to Install4j. I did a JRE update, so all classes are compiled using JDK 1.8. I converted one screen over to Install4j, by making it extend from AbstractInstallerScreen. I added all of the required methods from the base class. When I compile this class in Eclipse, and go back to the Install4j IDE, I can't add this screen as a custom screen. I get the message that says "Your custom code does not contain any classes implementing com.install4j.api.screens.InstallerScreen".

I added a path to this package inside the Install4j IDE.

The interesting thing about this is that I took the SampleScreen.class (found in the samples directory), added it to my package, and it found that screen. But, once I took that screen's java file, placed it in the package with the rest of my screens, and compiled it through Eclipse, the Install4j IDE no longer found the screen.

Is there something different between Eclipse's compilation and the standard Sun's JDK? Is it the fact that I dropped this screen in a package, making it necessary for me to define the package prior to compiling it?

I'm using Eclipse Juno. I can use any version (and I believe Juno will only compile up to JDK 1.7.)

Comment: Is there any related output in %TEMP%\install4j_error.log after you try to select the class? Are you sure that the class has been added to the Installer->Custom Code & Resources step? You can add the root directory that contains the compiled classes or a JAR file.

Comment: I don't have any install4j_error.log in my temp folder. I actually can't add my custom screen because the install4j doesn't allow me to select it from within its IDE. As soon as I select the menu add -> custom code -> search screen in custom code, I get an error message stating there are no classes that implement com.install4j.api.screens.InstallerScreen.

Comment: You have to add the custom code on the Installer->Custom Code & Resources step, otherwise you cannot add the screen.